# SharePoint Hybrid Search - Onboarding PowerShell Script

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, hybrid-solution

I am trying to implement the SharePoint Hybrid environment for SharePoint 2019 using the available PowerShell scripts.  Creating the Cloud SSA works fine and all, but when I run the *Onboard-CloudHybridSearch* I get the following error:

[image]

I have checked the onboard script to figure out why the error is presented.  It has to do with a missing registry key entry:

[image]

I don't have the MSOIdentityCRL registry key.

I am using Windows server 2019, which comes with the Microsoft Online services sign in assistant.  So shouldn't I have this reg key by default? Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the latest version of the Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell from the PowerShell Gallery?
Reference:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hybrid/configure-cloud-hybrid-searchroadmap#connect-your-cloud-search-service-application-to-your-microsoft-365-organization

Comment: I have yes.  Version 1.1.183.8

Comment: I suggest you open a ticket with Microsoft.